# Issue with Code Coverage in VS 2012

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, mstest, code-coverage

I have a simple ASP.Net MVC 4 application with 3 simple tests.

Each of these tests run successfully to completion, however the Code Coverage window gives me the following error:

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

I have done some research but nothing has resolved my problem to date.

- I know the tests run
- I have .pdb files in the same location as my .dll
- I am not optimsing by code
- I cannot find any .testsettings file
- I Have also run my VS 2012 Ultimate as Administrator, but no luck.

If I find the .coverage file, all it has in it is:

```
PCHÿ
```

Not the xmls results or error message I am expecting.

Comment: I had this problem, in my case it was solved when I ran Visual Studio as Administrator

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is over a year old. Nevertheless I have just encountered exactly the same issue, even down to the "PCHÿ" text in the .coverage file and have found no solution up 'til now. But surely someone else has had the issue too so, just in case, here's the simple solution:

After checking this [MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allendm/archive/2012/06/05/troubleshooting-missing-data-in-code-coverage-results.aspx) and following its advice I still had the same issue. So, in the end, I shutdown VS, went to the root solution directory and **deleted the .suo file**. It has the hidden attribute set so you might need to set explorer to show hidden files.

Restart VS and re-run the code coverage tests. All fine.

Comment: Hi Shunty.This problem still exists. I found elsewhere mention of removing he .suo file and restarting VS 2012, but still no luck. I also removed the entire TestResults folder and tried again, with no luck.

Comment: I haven't had the problem since so I can't give much more help. But, perhaps, if your code is under source control you could try checking it out to a new location and build/test it from there and see what happens. I'm sure it must be something to do with one of the transient/local files that VS manages and that shouldn't go into source control so it might work.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't make the Code Coverage to work even after you've deleted the *.suo file, please check your **Event Viewer** for errors. In my case, after each run I had the following error:

*"TraceLog Profiler failed in initialization due to a lack of instrumentation methods, process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe"*

I've found the answer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allendm/archive/2012/09/08/empty-coverage-file-with-profiler-related-errors-in-the-event-logs.aspx).

In case the link is no longer available, I'm pasting the content in here:

​

> If you find yourself with a an empty .coverage file and see errors
>   similar to the below in your event logs you most probably have a
>   corrupt install
>
> (info) .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.17929 - The profiler has
>   requested that the CLR instance not load the profiler into this
>   process. Profiler CLSID: '{b19f184a-cc62-4137-9a6f-af0f91730165}'.
>   Process ID (decimal): 12624. Message ID: [0x2516].
>
> (Error) TraceLog Profiler failed in initialization due to a lack of
>   instrumentation methods, process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
>
> Check
>
> a) Environment variable VS110COMNTOOLS is set to
>   \common7\tools
>
> b) Regkey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\InstallDir is set
>   to your \Common7\IDE\
>
> c) covrun32.dll and covrun64.dll exist in "\Team
>   Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage"

Good luck,

Nadav

Comment: I don't have `covrun64.dll` in my machine, and Code Coverage works fine. That's not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for help! In my case environment variable was set incorrectly. There were no error messages, just no code coverage result.

Comment: glad I could help ;-)