# Code Coverage Results periodically gives: Empty results generated

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I've run into a recurring problem with a few different projects using MSTest in VS2012, where every now and then my code coverage stops working (seemingly at random) and instead gives me:

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the
>   tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files,
>   and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

I've checked the obvious (what it's suggested) but can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

Here is my runsettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage"
                     uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0"
                     assemblyQualifiedName=" Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, 
                                             Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, 
                                             Version=11.0.0.0, 
                                             Culture=neutral, 
                                             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*\.tests.dll</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
            <Attributes>
              <Exclude>
                <Attribute>.*ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>.*GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
              </Exclude>
            </Attributes>

            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link solved my issue: [Issue with Code Coverage in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504992/issue-with-code-coverage-in-vs-2012)

Close Visual Studio 2012, find the .suo file, delete (or rename) it, restart. Worked fine. No idea what is in the .suo file that prevented proper coverage analysis.

Comment: It helped but for I am using VS 2019, I had to delete .vs folder.

Answer (score 30):

I just ran into this using Visual Studio 2019. The solution was to go to the "Test" menu item in VS and then update the Test -> Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects setting from X86 to X64.

Comment: This solved the problem for me in VS2019 16.4.2. Had a .Net Core 3.0 test project with 0% coverage. Change the platform target from "Any CPU" to "x64". Lo and behold, now it reports a coverage of 83%.

Comment: Upvote!  Also, screen shot here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250411/cant-analyze-code-coverage-with-visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 2):

If you can't make the Code Coverage to work even after you've deleted the *.suo file, please check your **Event Viewer** for errors. In my case, after each run I had the following error:

*"TraceLog Profiler failed in initialization due to a lack of instrumentation methods, process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe"*

I've found the answer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allendm/archive/2012/09/08/empty-coverage-file-with-profiler-related-errors-in-the-event-logs.aspx).

In case the link is no longer available, I'm pasting the content in here:

​

> If you find yourself with a an empty .coverage file and see errors
>   similar to the below in your event logs you most probably have a
>   corrupt install
>
> (info) .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.17929 - The profiler has
>   requested that the CLR instance not load the profiler into this
>   process. Profiler CLSID: '{b19f184a-cc62-4137-9a6f-af0f91730165}'.
>   Process ID (decimal): 12624. Message ID: [0x2516].
>
> (Error) TraceLog Profiler failed in initialization due to a lack of
>   instrumentation methods, process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
>
> Check
>
> a) Environment variable VS110COMNTOOLS is set to
>   \common7\tools
>
> b) Regkey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\InstallDir is set
>   to your \Common7\IDE\
>
> c) covrun32.dll and covrun64.dll exist in "\Team
>   Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage"

Good luck,

Nadav

Comment: Thanks! Updating the environment variables fixed the problem for one of my devs who initially installed on C: and then reinstalled on D:. Uninstalling/ reinstalling didn't update the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after running PerfView.

Re-running perfview having copied it into a folder of it's own  and starting a collection run, followed by stopping it seems to have fixed the issue.

I was getting 0x8007007e errors loading the profiler with a guid of {9999995d-2cbb-4893-be09-fce80abc7564} (Vs2015 profiler) and {6652970f-1756-5d8d-0805-e9aad152aa84} (perfview profiler)

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/816513/code-coverage-analysis-fails-to-find-any-code-to-a.html) in Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.3.0+ which results in the same error output and currently the workaround is to downgrade to 16.2.0 which worked for me.  In addition to the troubleshooting tips MS provides [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/troubleshooting-code-coverage?view=vs-2019) there may be SDK issues.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem I was experiencing right now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that my test dll path contained the string "DataCollector" and seems coverlet has an internal ignore over any path that matches something like .*DataCollector.*

Answer (score 0):

I modified the Property group associated with my debug environment so that it looks like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>OurProjectName.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

For my core.net 3.1 application running xUnit 2.4.1 this was the only thing that fixed it in visual studio 2019 preview.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Test -> Processor Architecture >> AnyCPU Projects setting >>> X86 to X64.This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and tried out all the above options but it did not work for me.

I could solve this problem only after creating full debug information. The settings for full debug information may vary from version to version. As I am using MSVS 2017, in the build menu there is a submenu which allows to have the full debug version.

I hope this will help others as well.