# Unit tests in VS2012 shows Empty results generated

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have created a test project with output type class library for my wpf application in visual studio 2012.

I am referencing all the project related binaries from a virtual drive (named R:) in which I also have all the associated .pdb files.

I have also checked option for "Enable Code analysis on Build" to true.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784290/vs2012-code-coverage-results-periodically-gives-empty-results-generated) link i also tried deleting .suo files and verified other reg key options. but still it shows "Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented" message and gives 0% coverage in output tab.
Please help out.

Comment: So... did you actually write a unit test?

Comment: yes. around 400 tests I have written which should have given me aroung 65-70% coverage. and they all are passing without any error if just click on Run tests.

Comment: also I didn't use any [DeplymentItem] attribute as my tests were specifically for C# code and I hope that's not the reason of coverage error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create just a simple ControlLibrary Project and import the testing-dlls? I usually don't create regular-testing projects. The simple ones just work finde after importing the quality tools dlls for MS-Test. Verify if you can see a simple test there. This should give you some path into the right direction. Also, you can compare the two projects in terms of settings.