# Can't analyze code coverage with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop and test a .NET Core application. A few months ago, I remember that all my tests are successful and I was able to launch a code  coverage analyze. Today I launched a code coverage analyze but it fails (tests are always successful):

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the
>   tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files,
>   and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information
>   see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

I have always upgraded my Visual Studio and the current version I have now is **Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.4.0)**

Any experience or feedback about this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strange enough setting the "Processor Architecture" to x64 worked for me:

See screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you by setting the Processor architecture to `x64` my problem is solved.

Comment: But I don't know how it worked before since I never set the Processor Architecture.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with a fresh installed VS 2019 Enterprise and a simple solution with two projects:

- static library
- native unit test project (testing the library above)

I got the same error "Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings."

The solution was to enable **"Profile"** on the linker section of the native unit test project.

[image]