# Why is CodeCoverage.exe producing near empty .coverage Files?

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage, visual-studio-2022

In our Jenkins pipeline, we use SonarQube to report on our code coverage.  After running all of our unit/integration tests to produce the .coverage file, we need to analyze this file to create the ".coverage.coveragexml" which is ultimately what is used by SonarQube to interpret the code coverage.  We do this by using the CodeCoverage.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\TestAgent\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"{somePath}\{someName}.coverage.coveragexml" "{somePath}\{someName}.coverage"
```

This command appears to be working, but when you run `dir /s *.coveragexml` (within the directory), it displays something like:

```
Directory of C:\jenkins\path\to\TestResults\coverageFile
03/22/2022  04:59 PM                64 ContainerAdministrator_DC420D3FA0BA_2022-03-22.16_46_43.coverage.coveragexml
1 File(s)             64 bytes
```

64 bytes is practically nothing - and I believe this is the reason why our SonarQube metrics show we have 0 coverage now.

I added the same `dir` command, only this time to check for the `.coverage` file(s), and those come back with only 10 bytes in them - making me think that these files are essentially empty.  I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784290/code-coverage-results-periodically-gives-empty-results-generated) that seems to be a similar issue.  The accepted answer said to change the platform type from x86 to x64, but that did not work in my case.

The vstest.console command for running our tests is:

```
vstest.console /Parallel /EnableCodeCoverage /Logger:trx /Platform:x86 ".\somePath\Test.dll"
```

This issue originally started back when we made a change to our Jenkinsfile for it to use Visual Studio 2022 instead of 2019 (the base image was updated) in the command that started the CodeCoverage executable.

What could be causing the coverage files to be nearly/completely empty and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the base image we use must have a non-enterprise edition of the Code Coverage tools (which is a [requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2022#requirements)).  We tested our SonarQube projects commands locally using an enterprise edition of the tools (I have Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise installed on my machine), and the coverage files produced contain the correct data.  However, when we used a Visual Studio Professional install, the files are empty just like our Jenkins pipeline.

As stated, this started happening when the base image was updated - in particular it was around [November 8th 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/pull/845).  It seems the base docker image we were using ([mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-20220210-windowsservercore-ltsc2019](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/?tab=description)) has the latest 2022 tools, but it must not be an enterprise edition - hence the empty files.

We switched our pipeline over to using [dotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html) instead to perform the analysis, which works as expected and our SonarQube coverage is back to normal.