# Code coverage error (No binaries were instrumented)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

### Problem:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

I'm attempting to use the code coverage function but it returns this error:

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the 
>   tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files,
>   and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

My .coverage file is full of non-sense, starting with "PCHÿ". I thought my problem looked similar to this one: [Issue with Code Coverage in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504992/issue-with-code-coverage-in-vs-2012), but deleting the .suo file and running Visual Studio in admnistrator didn't solve anything.

### How to replicate:

1) Create new empty project "MyProject"

2) Add new file "Calculator.hpp"

```
#pragma once

class Calculator
{
public:
    int add(int a, int b);
    int sub(int a, int b);
};
```

3) Add new file "Calculator.cpp"

```
#include "Calculator.hpp"

int Calculator::add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int Calculator::sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

4) Add new file main.cpp

```
#include "Calculator.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    Calculator calc;
    std::cout << calc.add(5, 11) << std::endl;
    std::cout << calc.add(11, 1) << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

5) Build solution. (0 errors)

6) Add new test project to solution as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx#objectRef:

1. Add new Native Unit Test Project to solution "CalculatorUnitTest"
2. Add "main.obj" and "Calculator.obj" to Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies of "CalculatorUnitTest"
3. Add path to obj files to Linker/General/Additional Library Directories of "CalculatorUnitTest". (In my case: D:\JF\Programming\Tests\MyProject\MyProject\Debug)
4. Add the header directory of "MyProject" to VC++ Directories/Include Directories. (In my case: D:\JF\Programming\Tests\MyProject\MyProject).

7) Replace code in "unittest1.cpp" with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <Calculator.hpp>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace CalculatorUnitTest
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            Calculator calc;
            Assert::AreEqual(5, calc.add(2, 3));
        }

    };
}
```

8) Build solution (0 errors, TestMethod1 appear in Test Explorer)

9) Right-click TestMethod1, "Run Selected Tests" (Test successfully passes)

10) Right-click TestMethod1, "Analyze Code Coverage for Selected Tests" (Code coverage fails).

At D:\JF\Programming\Tests\MyProject\Debug, I have both my MyProject.exe and MyProject.pdb with the CalculatorUnitTest.dll.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not sure if Visual Studio 2015 (C++) supports ".exe" type project for the unit test.  But you are using ".obj" directly from your project.  You need to place ".pdb" file in the same folder.

I created a static library project and added the unit test.  Same problem on my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Future here. Same problem, except my test target is a Static Library project in the same Solution.

- MyLib - Code that will be tested.
- MyLibTests - Project containing the tests.
- Solution contains both projects.
- MyLibTests has project Reference to MyLib.
- `<OutDir>` (in .vcxproj) aka Output Directory aka $(OutDir) identical in both projects. (My value `<OutDir>$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)_$(Platform)\</OutDir>`)

On your **test** project (MyLibTests), go

1. Properties
2. Select [**Debug**|*platform*]
3. Linker
4. Debugging

   1. Generate Debug Info = **Optimize for debugging /DEBUG**

Mine was initially set for **/DEBUG:FASTLINK**.

Via this [social MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ea2618b-670a-4041-87c4-82741085d566/code-coverage-generates-empty-results-no-binaries-were-instumented?forum=vsunittest) I figured it had something to do with the PDB, because MSDN (aka now "learn.microsoft.com") said this is an important step in several places, and I **assume** PDB are used trace calls, I **assume** using DbgHelp.dll.

And this sort of checklist modified from another [social MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddde3cdb-f70a-481c-8f7c-40ebfacb1afd/code-coverage-always-returns-empty-result-set?forum=vsunittest):

- Test project References properly set (*MyLib.lib is in the same Solution as MyLibTests.dll*)
- Build order/dependency set/verified.
- I also have Autorun on Build.
- Rebuild (this should rebuild dependencies).
- made sure all test were run(all test run successful)
- not using optimisation (Profile Guided/Instrumentation etc).
- `<OutDir>` aka Ouput directory should be the same, where both MyLibrary.lib/dll/exe ends up with their MyLibrary.pdb since PDB paths are linked in the exe/dll.
- not using a runsettings file
- Unload all other projects other than affected ones